# jQuery auto scroll to ID from different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have seen this problem on stackoverflow but the code that was used in there was different and I didn't really understood it. So I want to make website scroll to div when website is coming from another page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top -70 
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

This code works in homepage, scrolls smooth, but it does not work when it's clicked from another page.

Comment: Whats the link to the article you found? Why this doesn't work is you click to go to another page which in turn will render this script again but doesn't trigger the scroll as all is within your click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will scroll the body to the `#someDiv` top offset when page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#someDiv').offset().top - 70
    }, 800);

});
```

and this if the `referrer` is not `http://www.example.com`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if (document.referrer !== "http://www.example.com") {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#someDiv').offset().top - 70
        }, 800);
    }

});
```

and this when comes from other page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if(document.referrer != '' &&  document.referrer != location.href ){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#someDiv').offset().top - 70
        }, 800);
    }
});
```